# .NET Merge multiple 1/3 A4 docx files into A4 docx file

Tags: .net, merge, label, docx

I'm building an application that will be used for management of serial numbers and product information.

Now in a certain step of the product the user will be printing labels to stick onto the boxes of the finished product. These labels include data on the product such as type, specs, serial number, barcode and the likes.

The labels are Printed on 1/3 A4 stickers (3 per A4) sheet.

I start off from a template docx file (page size: 99mm height, 210mm width) which gets filled in with the product data.

After generating I end up with a bunch of docx files. Merging them into a single docx file is no problem, but I end up with a bunch of pages sized at 1/3 A4.

What I'd like to end up with is a single docx file with 3 of the 1/3 A4's per page.

What's preventing me from starting from an A4 sized template with 3 of the labels already on it and filling that is the fact that one series will often be for different customers and thus require different templates.

Does anyone have any idea how the above can be achieved?
Alternate solutions are very welcome too, if it can be done with something other than docx, with easily editable templates.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What prevents you from creating a new word file with normal A4 sizes and copying the contents of three files onto one page?

Comment: Basically the 3 files themselves are 1/3'd a4 size, but the contents doesn't completely fill it (have margins on top and bottom because the printer can't print on the top and bottom 6mm of the page.) If I'd paste them into a single document they wouldn't be correctly aligned with the printed labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was too fast to rule out Daniel Hilgarth's approach. 
By juggling around, adding a few empty paragraphs between each label I was able to position them correctly for printing on a 3x 1/3 A4 label sheet.

I used Novacode's DocX library to do this.

Made something in the line of:

```
        Private Sub MergeBoxDocuments(ByVal Docs As List(Of String))
        Dim FullDoc As Novacode.DocX = Novacode.DocX.Create(LocalDirs.QUE & "Test.docx")
        FullDoc.MarginBottom = 25
        FullDoc.MarginTop = 25
        FullDoc.MarginLeft = 30
        FullDoc.MarginRight = 30

        Dim Counter As Integer = 0
        For Each D As String In Docs
            Dim Doc As Novacode.DocX = Novacode.DocX.Load(D)
            For Each T As Novacode.Table In Doc.Tables
                T.Design = Novacode.TableDesign.TableGrid
                FullDoc.InsertTable(T)
                Counter += 1

                If Not Counter = 3 Then
                    FullDoc.InsertParagraph(" ")
                    FullDoc.InsertParagraph(" ")
                    FullDoc.InsertParagraph(" ")
                Else : Counter = 0 : End If
            Next
        Next
        FullDoc.Save()
    End Sub
```

Thanks Daniel.